# change properties of flash video object using jQuery/javascript/css

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, flash, iframe

I have an iframe which plays flash object  (video)

Inside the iframe it has

```
<object id="objectId" width="640" height"640" data="name.swf?v=1.2">
</object>
```

Now i tried to change the width and height of this object using javascript and jquery but its not changing !

Here is the code that i tried

```
$("#objectId").css({"width":"790px"})  //also tried without px
document.getElementById("objectId").style.width="790"
```

also `$("#objectId")` returns `[]` in console

I have this video embedded inside an iframe inside a div

the structure is like

```
<div id="container">
<iframe src="blabla/bla.swf">
<object id="objectId" width="640" height"640" data="name.swf?v=1.2">
</object>
</iframe>
</div>
```

So i tried to access the html inside the div using `$("#container").html()`
This returned only the iframe and not the contents generated inside it!!

Comment: Looking for a viable solution !

Answer (score 0):

I ran into a similar problem once. What you can try is like

```
var cssLink = document.createElement("link")
cssLink.href = "style.css";
cssLink .rel = "stylesheet";
cssLink .type = "text/css";
window.frames[0].document.body.appendChild(cssLink);
```

Try this out it may help you though i'm not sure but it worked for me.
Where the style.css is the css file where you specify your styling for the frame

Comment: will the css change affect the flash object?

Comment: yes in this css file whatever you set should affect the target because  the effect of the above code is same as including a css file in a html document. one more thing you can try is keep the object inside a div and set the height and width as auto in css and try adjusting the height and width of the div the object should automatically adjust.

Answer (score 0):

Well first you can fix the error you have in you code here

this **height"640"** must be **height="640"**

the Js should be this:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $('#objectId').css({'height': 300, 'width':300});
});
```